# Simple Screen Recorder sound problem

Tags: sound-recorder

I installed Simple Screen Recorder  . It recorded my screen cast but having internal sound noise. Can you please tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of pulse audio use ALSA as audio input backend. Then reduce your ubuntu mic volume to 50%.
It worked for me on Ubuntu 18 LTS.

Comment: doesnt work for me